# Moviepy - capture time on-click

Tags: video-editor

I'm trying to capture the time of a mouse click on a video clip. I see 'time, position, color' events in the console, but I want to catch the times of clicks in my script - to allow me to save clips based on user interaction.
All and any help appreciated.